# React.js - Passing change handler functions to deep nested form components

Tags: forms, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a form which I want to render using **React.js** and also allow user to edit the inputs and submit it to the server. It's a list of products. Each **tr** represents one product id whose quantity,name,price,category can be changed by user. It has **dropdown** and **text** inputs.

I want to break it down in following components:

1. ProductList
2. Product
3. CategoryDropdown

**ProductList** contains **Product** contains **CategoryDropdown**. Now I have to pass **handleCategoryChange** function to **CategoryDropDown** component. So **ProductList** will pass this as a prop to **Product** which will pass it as a prop to **CategoryDropDown**.

Is this the right way? What if my form becomes more complex with even deeper nested components? Should I keep passing the handler functions as a property from all the way up to all the way down? Or should I consider using **redux**?

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="productId" value="101"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="quantity"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="productName"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="productPrice"/></td>
            <td>
                <select name="productCategory">
                    <option value="1"> Soap </option>
                    <option value="2"> Shampoo </option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="productId" value="102"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="quantity"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="productName"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="productPrice"/></td>
            <td>
                <select name="productCategory">
                    <option value="1"> Soap </option>
                    <option value="2"> Shampoo </option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to maintain `product` component with `state` of form which have the `onCategoryChange` handler.

You need something like this.

**ProductList Component:**

```
class ProductList extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    this.state = {
      products: [...this.props.products]; //your actual products
    }
  }

  handleEachProduct(){
    //takes data from each product component
    //updates to products in state
  }
  handleSubmit(){
    //submiy entire products in state
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <table>
        {
          this.state.products.map(product => {
            return(
              <Product data={product} submitProduct={this.handleEachProduct.bind(this)} />
            )
          })
        }
      </table>
    )
  }
}
```

**Product Component.**

```
class Product extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    this.state = {
      quantity: value,
      productCategory: value
      //similarly all values
    }
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    this.setState(this.props.data);
  }
  onCategoryChange(e){
    this.setState({productCategory:e.target.value }, function(){
    this.props.submitProduct(this.state); //updates state of product to ProductList
    });
    //Similarly change handlers for all values in product
  }
  render(){
    retrun(
      <tr>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="productId" value="101"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="quantity"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="productName"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="productPrice"/></td>
            <td>
                <select name="productCategory" onChange={this.onCategoryChange}>
                    <option value="1"> Soap </option>
                    <option value="2"> Shampoo </option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort to almost code it up... Nice approach too

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass some sort of onChange function from the form down to all the children & subchildren.

Or you can use redux (or something similar) and save all this data in the store. Once the form is submitted you can grab everything from the store with no need to pass anything up and down the component tree.

Comment: You have essentially rephrased my question :-)

Comment: It depands on your application. If all you have is this form, then perhaps the best solution is to use a redux store. 
If you have a larger application and you dont want to add temp form values to the store then you can pass onChange down the tree. It really depends on what you have. Using redux (or something similar) is usually a better approach but it might be an overkill to what you have.